# $(window).scroll() giving inaccurate results :(

Tags: jquery, css, position, parallax

I am using $(window).on('scroll') to conditionally set an absolutely positioned elements' top CSS value based on the return from $(window).scrollTop() from within the scroll event handling function.

Basically this will scroll the item WITH the page (like fixed pos) until the stop point has been reached, at which point the element should stop scrolling.

I am then using $(window).scrollTop() to find the amount that the page as been scrolled vertically and then offsetting/incrementing the target elements top css property with the scroll from top integer amount (in px).

I then have a data-attribute which describes where the scrolling effect will stop.

It appears at first that this approach is working as expected, however during testing I see that the speed at which the user scrolls down effects the position where the actual element stops having its CSS updated. Why wont my element stop where is supposed to.. and why if I scroll down and then back up does the element not return to its exact original position?

Here are the codez:

```
 /**
 * Will add the amount scroll from top of doc to the top css 
 * prop on the targeted item and stop the item at a specified amount from top
 * as well as debounce the events as they are scrolled 
 */

;(function parallaxTest(){
var lastScrollPoint = 0, lastScrollEvent = 0, captureEventInt = 1;
var parallax = function(){
  // Throttle the events to only use every other 1 (%50 reduction)
  if (lastScrollEvent !== captureEventInt){
    console.log(lastScrollEvent+' debounced');
    // Auto incr the lastScrollEvent tracking until it matches the above index value 
    lastScrollEvent++;
    // Ignore every other event that comes from user scroll
    return;
  }
  else {
    var distToTopInt = $(window).scrollTop(), target = $('button'),
        speedFlt = parseFloat(target.attr('data-parallax-speed')),
        distToStopAtInt = parseFloat(target.data('parallax-stop-at'));
    /**
    * Gets the direction of the users scroll while scrolling
    * @param {Int} currentScroll the px amount that the user is scroll to from top of window
    * @param {Int} prevScroll the px amount of the $(window) when last functioning scroll event fired prior to this one
    * @return {String} down | up
    **/
    var getScrollDir = function(currentScroll, prevScroll){
      if  (currentScroll > prevScroll){ 
        return 'down'; 
      } 
      else { 
        return 'up';
      };
    };

    if (distToTopInt <= distToStopAtInt){

      if (getScrollDir(distToTopInt, lastScrollPoint) === 'down') {
        target.css('top', '+='+distToTopInt +'px');
      }

      else if (getScrollDir(distToTopInt, lastScrollPoint) === 'up') {
        target.css('top', '-='+distToTopInt+'px');
      }
    }
    lastScrollPoint = distToTopInt;
    console.log(lastScrollEvent+' used');
    lastScrollEvent = 0;
  }
}
$(window).on('scroll', parallax);
})();
```

[image: Slow scrolling freezes the element here:]
[image: Fast scrolling freezes the element here:]

Here is the code broken down to the actual issue:

Steps to recreate:

Scroll slow, now see where the button stops being incremented.
Scroll fast, now see where the button stops being incremented.

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/WbdrJd

I have researched here and elsewhere but cannot find a solution to why this is happening! HELLLPPP...

Comment: I have added debouncing to the orig code, and this did help the accuracy a bit however it also introduced some jank to the scroll. Here is the updated code http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/WbdrJd